# How to make my welcome text appear?

Tags: python, facebook

After login, I want the text "Welcome, Niklas" to display but after logging in I have to reload the [page](http://www.koolbusiness.com/example) and I didn't understand how to make the page display the text from the server variable `current_user`. If I login and press reload then the correct welcome message appears. Can you help me achieve what I want? Why is there no simple working example for FB python + javascript? Can I implement facebook connect without javascript? If so, do I have to use and set the cookie myself? Thank you

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head> 
    <title> 
      Test Facebook SDK
    </title> 
  </head> 
<body> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '164355773607006', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.KOOLBUSINESS.COM/static/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
{% if current_user %}
<div id="user-ident">
<span>{% trans "Welcome," %} <b>{{ current_user.name|escape }}</b></span>
</div>
{% endif %}
</body> 
</html>
```

Here's how I get the variable `current_user`

```
@property
def current_user(self):
    if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
        self._current_user = None
        cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
            self.request.cookies, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
        logging.debug("logging cookie"+str(cookie))
        if cookie:
            # Store a local instance of the user data so we don't need
            # a round-trip to Facebook on every request
            user = FBUser.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
            logging.debug("user "+str(user))
            logging.debug("username "+str(user.name))

            if not user:
                graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                profile = graph.get_object("me")
                user = FBUser(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                            id=str(profile["id"]),
                            name=profile["name"],
                            profile_url=profile["link"],
                            access_token=cookie["access_token"])
                user.put()
            elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                user.put()
            self._current_user = user
    return self._current_user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Oauth 2.0

```
FB.Init(...oauth=true)
```

the login button is setting a cookie into your domain named

```
fbsr_(appid)=....
```

which is encoded using the *app secret key*, and which do not contain the *user token* anymore.

If you really want to avoid the use of java script client side (which is the most simple way) you can leverage the presence of this cookie to know if the user is connected to facebook and then perform any authorization check or dynamically display a welcome message.

I do not use python, so i do not have working example, but this give you a way to search.

Hope this help.